# Trouble creating a virtualenv for python3 on OS X

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I'm having a strange problem with a `virtualenv` I've created for python 3.  I went through the usual steps:

```
$ virtualenv --python=/opt/local/bin/python3.3 .py3
$ source .py3/bin/activate
```

The problem I'm having is that when I call `python --version`, it is still reporting 2.7.5, even though the paths all appear to be set up correctly.  My `virtualenv` was created in `/Users/barry.flinn/projects/.py3/bin`, and I get thes results when I run `which python`:

```
$ which python
/Users/barry.flinn/projects/.py3/bin/python
```

The bin folder has the following python executables:

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 barry.flinn  obfuscated\Domain Users     9 Sep 23 19:39 python -> python3.3
lrwxr-xr-x   1 barry.flinn  obfuscated\Domain Users     9 Sep 23 19:39 python3 -> python3.3
-rwxr-xr-x   1 barry.flinn  obfuscated\Domain Users  9100 Sep 23 19:39 python3.3
```

Clearly, invoking `python` should give me python 3.3, and yet it still seems to revert to the system python, which is 2.7.5.  My `$PATH` when the `virtualenv` is active is:

```
 /Users/barry.flinn/projects/.py3/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/local/lib/postgresql92/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/munki
```

Since all of this seems correct, I'm stumped as to what is going on here.

Update:

This reports correctly:

```
$ env python --version
Python 3.3.2
```

Which, to me, is slightly more baffling.

Comment: Do you perhaps have an alias defined for `python`?

Comment: D**n it, there was an alias `~/.bashrc`, that I didn't know about.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a shell alias defined for the `python` interpreter, it will override the python chosen for your virtualenv. For example:

```
user@x790:~/temp$ alias python=/usr/bin/python
user@x790:~/temp$ python --version
Python 2.7.4
user@x790:~/temp$ virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 foo
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in foo/bin/python3
Also creating executable in foo/bin/python
Installing distribute.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
Installing pip................done.
user@x790:~/temp$ . foo/bin/activate
(foo)user@x790:~/temp$ python --version
Python 2.7.4
```

Note that the python version reported was 2.7.4, even though python3 was selected for the virtualenv. Using the `env` command circumvents the alias:

```
(foo)user@x790:~/temp$ env python --version
Python 3.3.1
```

Lastly, you can get around this issue by either temporarily disabling the python alias for a single command or permanently undefining it:

```
(foo)user@x790:~/temp$ \python --version
Python 3.3.1
(foo)user@x790:~/temp$ unalias python
(foo)user@x790:~/temp$ python --version
Python 3.3.1
```

Comment: @bogatron could you explain it more clearly, I still dont know how to deal with it. when I try to run: `virtualenv --python /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/Python three_py` instead of creating new virtualenv named three_py in current location directory it activates one of the virtualenvs.

Comment: Looks like you are missing an "=" sign. It should be `virtualenv --python=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/Python three_py`. As for the actual path in your statement, I don't know if that is correct or not (I can't tell if it points to an executable or a directory).